# Date format issue while writing xlsx in R

Tags: r, excel, date, xlsx, r-xlsx

Exp is a data frame , as given below:

```
> Exp
  Branch       Date Division
1      2 2023-02-10      820
2      2 2023-02-10      280
3      2 2023-02-10      935
4      2 2023-02-10      359
5      2 2023-02-10      450
> str(Exp)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Branch  : num  2 2 2 2 2
 $ Date    : Date, format: "2023-02-10" "2023-02-10" "2023-02-10" ...
 $ Division: num  820 280 935 359 450
```

When I try to export it to excel using

```
options(xlsx.date.format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(Exp, file = "Exp.xlsx", sheetName = "Expfile")
```

the output is the following:
[image]

I want the date to be appear as 2023-02-10 as shown in the data frame while writing data in Excel and not as 02.10.2023, when it is opened. Something is going wrong, despite setting options and Date being in date format as you see. What is missing here?

Comment: I tried with options(xlsx.date.format = "yyyy-MM-dd") and it did't help. The output has 02.10.2023 as usual, unfortunately.

Comment: Hey Darren, It worked wonderful. Thanks a lot. Could you please pose this as an answer to upvote it?

Comment: Hi, if my answer has solved your question, you could consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the package `{xlsx}`(Java dependent), the `xlsx.date.format` option need to be specified in [Java date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), where `mm` means minutes and `MM` means months. So you should do

```r
options(xlsx.date.format = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

If that still doesn't work, you can turn to another package `{openxlsx}`.

```r
library(openxlsx)
options(openxlsx.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd")
write.xlsx(list(Expfile = Exp), file = "Exp.xlsx")
```

where `Expfile` is the sheet name.